# How do you do an Object_Insert with a join on Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

On Snowflake the only way to update objects is through an object insert, but I need to update these objects using a join from another table. How do I do an object_insert with joins on snowflake?

Comment: Did the answer work? https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3):

the parts are somewhat separate:

There is the [UPDATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/update.html) table FROM / WHERE which is where you do the update, and the new data comes from the FROM/WHERE

So from the 2 tables UPDATE example you have:

```
update t1
  set 
    number_column = t1.number_column + t2.number_column, 
    t1.text_column = 'ASDF'
  from t2
  where t1.key_column = t2.t1_key and t1.number_column < 10;
```

so you weave in the [object_insert](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_insert.html) might become:

```
update t1
  set 
    number_column = t1.number_column + t2.number_column, 
    t1.text_column = 'ASDF',
    t1.awesome_json = OBJECT_INSERT( t1.awesome_json, 'add_new_field', t2.number_column, false),
    t1.other_json = OBJECT_INSERT( t1.other_json, 'update_field', t2.number_column, true)
  from t2
  where t1.key_column = t2.t1_key and t1.number_column < 10;
```